# How to keep track, store and traverse a huge spherical data structure

Tags: database, data-structures

I'm trying to generate a universe (represented as a sphere) with randomly placed black holes, galaxies, stars and planets (according to some basic rules). This huge data structure needs to be able to be traversed efficiently as I'll be "visiting" the objects in this universe periodically to update things.

Of course, something like this requires coordinates. I've settled on using polar coordinates for now.

So, in summary, I'm looking for the best way to store a set of coordinates that can be traversed and which represent objects.

The ways I've mulled over so far:

- A map with each coordinate as the key and the value being the contents of that location.
- A three dimensional array using the three "axis" of polar coordinates as indexes (ie, universe[phi][theta][r]).
- Some sort of linked list of coordinate objects.

This is probably going to be implemented in NodeJS. Given this, and what I've outline above, what would be the most efficient data structure? Are there issues I haven't thought of yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search Google for Oct trees and related space partitioning data structures.

Comment: Thanks, this led me down the right path.